# Calling/Scheduling multiple SSIS jobs for ETL process - what is one fails?

Tags: t-sql, ssis, etl

So I've got a procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[use___MasterLoadAll]
AS
--Must run in order
EXEC [dbo].[use__MasterLoad.Staging];
EXEC [dbo].[use__MasterApplyBRs];
EXEC [dbo].[use__MasterLoad.pdw.*];
EXEC [dbo].[use__MasterLoad.FPDW_Cube];
```

My issue is if the Business Rules fail on the controller I'd like to stop the procedure - Here is what's in the EXEC [dbo].[use__MasterApplyBRs]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[use__MasterApplyBRs]
AS
EXEC [dbo].[usp_ApplyDMBusinessRules];
EXEC [dbo].[usp_ApplyIndirectBusinessRules];
```

Then EXEC [dbo].[usp_ApplyDMBusinessRules]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ApplyDMBusinessRules]
AS
-- Set up the exection
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'DMController.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, 
@folder_name=N'StagingImport', @project_name=N'BusRulesDirect', @use32bitruntime=False, @reference_id=Null
DECLARE @DWConnStr sql_variant = N'Data Source=DWSERVER;Initial Catalog=DataWarehouse;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;'
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=20, @parameter_name=N'ppDWConnStr', @parameter_value=@DWConnStr

-- System params
DECLARE @LOGGING_LEVEL smallint = 3
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', @parameter_value=@LOGGING_LEVEL
DECLARE @Sync smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'SYNCHRONIZED', @parameter_value=@Sync

-- Execute package
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id

IF EXISTS (select 1 FROM ssisdb.catalog.executions where execution_id = @execution_id AND status = 4)
RAISERROR('Start with Google; End with http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask', 16, 1)
```

Then EXEC [dbo].[usp_ApplyIndirectBusinessRules]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ApplyIndirectBusinessRules]
AS

-- Set up the exection
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'InDirectController.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, 
@folder_name=N'StagingImport', @project_name=N'BusRulesIndirect', @use32bitruntime=False, @reference_id=Null
DECLARE @DWConnStr sql_variant = N'Data Source=DWSERVER;Initial Catalog=DataWarehouse;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;'
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=20, @parameter_name=N'ppDWConnStr', @parameter_value=@DWConnStr

-- System params
DECLARE @LOGGING_LEVEL smallint = 3
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', @parameter_value=@LOGGING_LEVEL
DECLARE @Sync smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'SYNCHRONIZED', @parameter_value=@Sync

-- Execute package
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id

IF EXISTS (select 1 FROM ssisdb.catalog.executions where execution_id = @execution_id AND status = 4)
RAISERROR('Start with Google; End with http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask', 16, 1)
```

So finally each of those controllers have similar TSQL that calls a bunch of Business Rules Packages - but if anyone of those packages fails the Controller will continue and end reporting failure -

Therefore if a Controller reports failure within the Business Rules I need MasterLoadAll to stop - How?

Comment: Found a link that may help [from Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) on error handling. Basically, the keys appear to be (1) use `TRY...CATCH` around *everything*; (2) always re-raise errors in the `CATCH` block; and (3) use the fact that every stored procedure returns an integer value, 0 by default. So, always return a non-zero value when a stored proc fails. See the link for the full details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a SQL job to run the packages? 
If each package fails when an error occurs, you can have your job exit immediately.

Just an idea...

Comment: Nestor - Yes I have, that's the "easy" way - I'm new and trying to learn alternative approaches to similar problems.  It's currently running in a SQL Job, but I'd like to understand the code.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Got it. I think the try...catch option that RDFozz commented is probably a good place to start.